# matter.js: collisionStart triggered many times for one collision

Tags: javascript, react-native, matter.js

I am working on a game app using React native and Matter.js.

I am trying to implement a system that adds points every time a bullet hits a target.

In order to do this, I am trying to use collisionStart to detect the collision.

However, even though the bullet and target collide only once, the event seems to be triggered 41 times.

This is the code:

```
Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {
    let pairs = event.pairs
    for (const pair of pairs) {
      if (pair.bodyA.label === 'bullet' && pair.bodyB.label === 'Worm') {
        console.log("target hit");
      }
    }
  })
```

In the end, I'm planning to replace console.log with something that adds points. At the current moment, one collision seems like it would trigger the add points 41 times, which is obviously not ideal.

Any ideas what is happening here and how I can get this to trigger only once for one collision?

Comment: Are you doing anything to resolve the collision once it happens, e.g. destroy one of the bodies or move them apart? If not, well, then on the next frame if the collision is still happening, the handler will dutifully fire as you're asking it to.

Comment: We tried all sorts including deleting, moving etc, but the collision was still being shown to have happened 40+ times. We concluded that it must have been how React native was running the game engine, since we switched from React to something else for the graphics (keeping matter.js for the physics) and one collision sparked only one collision event..

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's interesting -- could you provide a [mcve] of the problematic code with the moving/deleting variants, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try next example. I take it from my own project [you need little adaptd from ts to js]:

```
    Matter.Events.on(this.starter.getEngine(), "collisionStart", function (event) {
      root.collisionCheck(event, true);
    });
```

```
 public collisionCheck(event, ground: boolean) {

    const myInstance = this;

    const pairs = event.pairs;
    for (let i = 0, j = pairs.length; i !== j; ++i) {
      const pair = pairs[i];
      if (pair.activeContacts) {
        if (pair.bodyA.label === "bullet" && pair.bodyB.label === "Worm") {
          const collectitem = pair.bodyA;
          this.playerDie(collectitem);
        } else if (pair.bodyB.label === "bullet" && pair.bodyA.label === "Worm") {
          const collectitem = pair.bodyB;
          this.playerDie(collectitem);
        }

         // ....
        }
      }

  }
```

```
 public destroyBody = (destroyBody) => {
    try {
    Matter.Composite.remove(this.getWorld(), destroyBody);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

If you still have same problem , we can adapt also with flag PREVENT_DOUBLE_BY_1_SECOUND for example.

Comment: Thanks for the example! Just wondering if you were doing this within React Native?

Comment: You no need to react at all. If you wanna android , take android studio and use chrome web control. If you need desktop use visual studio or xcode for macos.